# Return the same type as subclass calling a base method

Tags: c#, inheritance

A very simple base class:

```
class Figure {
    public List<?> getList() {
        var list = new List<same as child>();
        //do some code
        //filling list
        return list;
    }
}
```

This inheriting class:

```
class Rectangle : Figure
{
    
}
class Cube : Figure
{
    
}
```

I know I could use the generic like this:

```
class Figure {
    public List<T> getList<T>() {
        var list = new List<T>();
        //do some code
        //filling list
        return list;
    }
}

Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
List<Rectangle> lRec = rec.getList<Rectangle>();

Cube cube = new Cube();
List<Cube> lCube = cube.getList<Cube>();
```

But I want to know if there is an alternative

Like this:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
List<Rectangle> lRec = rec.getList();

Cube cube = new Cube();
List<Cube> lCube = cube.getList();
```

Comment: An alternative that does what differently and why/what is your goal?

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't want to write the type every time I call the method, because is always the same as the subclass that is calling it.

Comment: This breaks `SOLID` big time.. Usually a `Factory` class is used for this kind of tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you constraint the type parameter to the implementing class
you get what you're looking for:

```
class Figure<T> where T : Figure<T>
{
    public List<T> getList()
    {
        var list = new List<T> ();
        //do some code
        //filling list
        return list;
    }
}

class Rectangle : Figure<Rectangle>
{

}
class Cube : Figure<Cube>
{

}
```

Depending on the scenario marking `getList` as virtual or abstract might come in handy